# What unit of width should I use (px or % or em) for columns in a grid/ table [number of columns differ for different users]-CSS

Tags: css

I have a table that has 10 columns and for an advanced user, there would be 20 columns. So the column width would change based on the user. I was using 'px' to specify the size of each column. Is 'px' best way of doing it? The programmer before me used '%' for another grid (unlike mine, it had fixed number of columns).
This application would run on IE8/ IE9.

Intent of question: Is 'px' best way to specify width in situations where the column numbers might change frequently.

Comment: it depends on whether or not you want your columns to resize with the screen width.  Normally % are better to use for a grid system, but it really depends on the future-proofing of your site

Comment: If you can, use Bootstrap instead: http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: @jmargolisvt I have to respectfully say that's not always the best option.  "If you need a bloated framework to start theming like you would a wordpress site, and you want a grid system, use bootstrap"  If you want to make a grid system, make a grid system - it's not tough

Comment: I need the width of the table to be constant, but the column width can change. Even I think % is better. but someone told me to use px instead of % (without any explanation). That's why I posted this question.

Comment: if the width of the table is the same (and is going to be the same FOREVER) then you can use px.  The only reason I wouldn't use % at that point is because of remainder pixels and how each browser/OS combo rounds up or down the remaining percentage of a pixel.

Comment: For e.g. if table width is 800px and column sizes add upto only 200 px, what would happen to the rest of the screen. My concern is only with different versions of IE show different outputs. (Not sure in this case)

Comment: It will usually just float to the left unless you specify where the grid should lay.  You may want to do some research on different grid systems.  the 960 grid is plain and simple, there's a 960 grid with a column pusher so you can place a single column anywhere (without fill columns) There's tons of options. here's an example https://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-it-grids/  I don't use that one, but it's just a starting point

Comment: I am facing issue with adjusting the fields in case of 20 columns, I am adjusting 2-3 px to make sure all the data is getting displayed completely. This is very frustrating as some of them are currency fields. I specify it to be 40px, it's ok with small values, but for large values the column size increases. I can't use the scroll bar nor can I increase the width of the column.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest you are overcomplicating matters for yourself. Its true that vanilla frameworks are bloated but you can cut out what you don't need and use the rest.

Por ejemplo:

**Foundation 4 Grid Framework**
http://foundation.zurb.com/develop/download-f4.html

**Patch for IE8+**
https://gist.github.com/hatefulcrawdad/5068210

To answer you original question however, **there is no right answer**. You can have a column framework using pixel widths using the older methods of **floating and clearing**

You could also have a **percentage based framework** which uses a pixel based container to simulate pixel widths.

**In Short**

I recommend you study the CSS on grid systems such as Bootstrap, 960Grid and Foundation **(my personal recommendation)** and how they work for you.

Then develop your own based off the system you prefer. You'll also gain a better understanding of Grid System development.